# Maya - query animation curve data

Tags: python, animation, maya, bezier, curve

I have a problem to query on deeper level Maya's animation curve data.
So as input I want to have an animation curve that is not connected to any attribure, just single node.
Having this I want to create a function that either returns:

1. Value with given time (I know that this can be easly done by connecting this anim curve to any attibute and then grabbing value by using command like: `cmds.getAttr([objName]+'.'[attrName], t=[timeValue]`...but how to do it without connecting animation curve to anything?)
2. Time with given value - I couldnt get it using any Maya commands and this is what I need the most.. :(

This is playing with bezier curve equation basicly but I'm pretty sure that Maya API is needed here but because Im very basic with API need your help:), any clues how to solve this? Thanks!!

Comment: Just to be clear, you're expecting a list of timings when searching from a given value? It's easily possible to have the same value for many frames.

Comment: Basicly yes but to make things more specific, I want to get time by giving value without having a keyframe at this place. So for example I have an anim curve with 2 keys: first key is at frame 0 with value 0, second key is on frame 10 and value 10. Now I want to check time for value between 0 and 10, lets say 3.5  ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keyframe` to query an anim curve's values that isn't connected to any attribute. Here's an example that will create an anim curve with 2 keys, print the key values, then print its value at each frame:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

# Create an animation curve with 2 keys.
anim_curve = cmds.createNode("animCurveTL")
cmds.setKeyframe(anim_curve, t=0, v=0)
cmds.setKeyframe(anim_curve, t=10, v=10)

# Get its key count.
key_count = cmds.keyframe(anim_curve, q=True, keyframeCount=True)

# Iterate through key count and print all key values.
for i in range(key_count):
    print cmds.keyframe(anim_curve, q=True, index=(i, i))[0]

# Get the scene's frame ranges.
start = int(cmds.playbackOptions(q=True, min=True))
end = int(cmds.playbackOptions(q=True, max=True))

# Iterate through each frame and print the anim curve's value.
for f in range(start, end):
    print f, cmds.keyframe(anim_curve, q=True, eval=True, time=(f, f))[0]
```

Getting a value at a given time is easy enough, that's what the last portion is doing.

Getting a time with a given value isn't though, and you may need to re-think your approach. First of all it's possible to have the value during sub-frames, but I'm assuming you'd want to ignore that. Also you're trying to match a float value, which is tricky in programming. As a value of 3.5 will not match a value of 3.5000001, which is likely the kind of values the curve will have since it's interpolating between the keyed values.

But if you insist on doing it then you probably need to compare the value on every frame between the curve's first/last key times. When you compare the value you might need some threshold that is deemed acceptable, or close enough, to solve precision issues. If it passes then you can append the time to a `list` and `return` it later.

Hope that points you to the right direction.

Comment: I got your point and as you wrote, I re-think'ed my approach (I wanted to avoid comparing values on every frame). Also I need to sample sub-frames which makes my problem more difficult but I found a different solution to make it work in my script so hope this will work :) ... 
Anyways thank you so much tor your time trying to solve this!